# String type in c++builder (RAD XE2) handle 2047 character only?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, c++builder-xe2

I have a project with Indy (using RAD XE2) and I get a return string from IdHTTP like:
String result = IdHTTP->Get(url);
the problem is reuslt is limited at 2047 character lenght. 
How can i handle full return string?
Thank you.

Edit: This issue occurs when in debug mode only (using Step into).

Comment: That's not an issue with the `String` or `WideString` type, but will either be an issue with Indy or the web service you're attempting to consume!

Comment: Strings in 32-bit C++Bulder applications are not limited to 2047 bytes; they can hold up to 2GB. It's something you're doing wrong, but as you've posted zero code it's hard to say what that might be.

Comment: Thank LaKraven and Ken White.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no inherent limit to the length of a string. More likely is that your debugging activities are interrupting the network activities, interfering with your program's ability to read everything off the socket before the debugger pauses it.

Stop trying to single-step through asynchronous I/O, and you'll probably see better results.

Also note that the debugger's watch window won't necessarily show you the entire contents of a variable, so if you're only seeing 2047 characters in the debugger, that doesn't necessarily reflect the actual length of the string. Call `Length` instead.